# how to make Sloped and looping ground objects in Clickteam Fusion 2.5

Tags: clickteam-fusion

I'm new to clickteam fusion 2.5, and I am attempting to learn how to make 2d games like Mario or Sonic which include sloped and/or looping surfaces but I'm unsure how I would make those shapes happen as the only object shapes are circle, square, or line (haven't figured out what line shape means yet).

in my testing i tried making some slope objects with line shape and tried seeing how a round object would behave, it just treats it as a square object and stops on it.

Comment: In Unity they draw a "raycast" (invisible line) from the centre of the character, downwards to get the floor collision. They can use the "normal" of the floor to find its angle and allow movement only upto a set angle (say 45 degrees for example). Once you do that, you can also use that angle to alter the speed of the player etc.    Alternatively, you can add a physics library and use that (but I don't recommend going down that road for a game like Mario personally). Sorry but I never used Fusion or anything like that. But thought I'd share what little I do know about it.

Comment: I do plan to try learning unity at some point as well so that info is useful

Comment: Hey, I hope you are on the way to solving your problem. By coincidence, I just happened across this video and I think this part is very relevant for you (I linked it roughly the correct time): https://youtu.be/EHlaJvQpW3U?t=1329

Comment: ive found a couple videos that may be useful, at least for slopes I'm still checking around for any that might explain how a loop object like a sonic game would have but so far i only get looping actions which isn't the same.

the video you linked may be useful in the future

Comment: That is an interesting question yes. I have no idea how the Sonic loop was handled. If I had to guess I would say that Sonic's colliding box is a circle, and they might using velocity values for his movement. If the x velocity is above a certain value, he continues around the "slope/wall" and if not he falls. Just a total guess now, sorry I couldn't be more helpful.

Comment: that makes sense, and it might be the case